# For which API levels is EmojiCompat needed?

Tags: android, emoji

In `build.gradle` I have the following: `minSdkVersion 17`
I decided to play around a bit with emojis.

The [EmojiCompat](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat.html) documentation states:

> The EmojiCompat support library provides classes to implement
>   **backward-compatible** emoji support on devices running Android 4.4 (API
>   level 19) and **higher**.

Rather confusing. For which API levels is the EmojiCompat library needed?

Comment: like it states. Android 4.4 and above. API 19 +

Comment: Care to elaborate? Previous "support libraries" were needed up to a certain API level... Is level 19 where the added native support for unicode emojis or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says on documentation [FAQ](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat.html)

```
What happens if I add widgets in layout XMLs on devices that run on Android 4.4 (API level 19) or lower?
```

> You can include the EmojiCompat support library or its widgets in
>   your applications that support devices running Android 4.4 (API level
>   19) or lower. However, if a device runs on an Android version prior to
>   API level 19, EmojiCompat and its widgets are in a "no operation"
>   state. This means that EmojiTextView behaves exactly like a regular
>   TextView. EmojiCompat instance; it immediately gets into a
>   LOAD_STATE_SUCCEEDED state when you call the init() method.

That should answer your question.

Comment: So even if you are on e.g. API level 27, there is no guarantee that a specific emoji is available on the device? Or is there a level where you don't need the library?

Comment: They are saying about versions lower to 19. Higher API levels should work  well with this.
For higher versions if it incompatible it would give you error in build